# Cookie Set in Response Headers But Undefined When Accessed in Frontend Using Express.js and Cookie-Parser

Tags: authentication, web, cookies, jwt, backend

I'm facing an issue with handling cookies in my Node.js application. I have an `accessToken` cookie that is set correctly when I make requests using Postman, but I'm unable to access it in my frontend.

Here's my code for setting the `accessToken` cookie:

```js
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import createError from "../utils/createError.js";

export const login = async (req , res, next) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username });
            
    if (!user) return next(createError(404, "User not found!"));
    
    const isCorrect = bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password);
    if (!isCorrect) return next(createError(400, "Wrong password or username!"));
    
    console.log("Generating token with isSeller:", user.isSeller);
    const token = jwt.sign(
      {
        id: user._id,
        isSeller: user.isSeller,
      },
      process.env.JWT_KEY
    );
    console.log("Token generated:", token);
    
    const { password, ...info } = user._doc;
    res
      .cookie("accessToken", token, {
        httpOnly: false,
      })
      .status(200)
      .send(info);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};
Additionally, here's my verifyToken code:
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import createError from "../utils/createError.js";

export const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.cookies.accessToken;
  console.log(token);
  if (!token) {
     return next(createError(401,"You are not authenticated!"))
  }

  jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_KEY, async (err, payload) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(createError(403,"Token is not valid!"))
    }
    req.userId = payload.id;
    req.isSeller = payload.isSeller;
    next();
  });
};
In this code, I'm using req.cookies.accessToken to retrieve the accessToken cookie, and I've verified that the cookie-parser middleware is correctly implemented.

When I check the network requests in my browser's developer tools, I can see that the accessToken cookie is present in the headers. However, when I try to access it using req.cookies.accessToken in my frontend, it returns undefined.

Can anyone help me understand why I can't access the accessToken cookie in my frontend even though it's present in the headers?
```

Comment: Is it an [HTTP-only cookie](https://owasp.org/www-community/HttpOnly) that isn't available to JavaScript?

Comment: i have done httpOnly to true as well and nothing changes